# Linq related table not queryable error

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I've got a problem with Linq in VB.NET.
I've created a .dbml file from my db, and everything looks good - relation "arrows" between tables are visible, etc.

But when I want to use simple query (taken from 101 Linq Samples by MS):

```
Dim q = From h In dc.Hours, w In h.WorkType
```

I receive an error:

> Expression of type 'INTegrity.WorkType' is not queryable. Make sure you are not missing an assembly reference and/or namespace import for the LINQ provider.

h.Worktype is visible in Intellisense...

I can manually join in the Linq query, but shouldn't the relations be automatic?

The full query that works, but using "manual joins" looks like this:

```
Dim q1 = From g In dc1.Hours _ 
Join pr In dc1.WorkType On g.WorkTypeId Equals pr.WorkTypeId _ 
Where g.WorkerId = workerid _ 
Select New With {g.EntryId, g.Date, pr.WorkTypeDesc, g.Minutes}
```

Worktype table has 1 to many relationship with Hours table (as you can see on the WorkTypeId column)

Comment: Linq in VB is foreign to me, but I am very familiar with Linq in C#. It doesn't look like you are doing anything with this query. Are you trying to write a join? Where is your select?

Comment: The error is displayed when I write the first line, I don't even get to select. And yes, I would like to make a join using relation information from the .dbml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't speak LINQ in VB, so I'll try to adapt to C#

```
From h In dc.Hours, w In h.WorkType 

from h in dc.Hours
from w in h.WorkType
.....
```

This implies that WorkType is a collection, which it's name does not suggest.  I think you want something closer to

```
from h in dc.Hours
let w = h.WorkType 
....
```

Of course, none of these will do anything without the parts in the "....".  If you show us what you want to do there, we could probably fix it for you.

UPDATE#1:

Trying to piece together what you are doing, let's guess that Hours & WorkType are tables with a one-to-many relationship (WorkType on the "one" side), hence every Hours record matchs one WorkType record.   In that case, Linq-to-SQL will automatically generate a *scalar* WorkType property in Hours.  You don't need the "from ... in " to access it.  It's just a property, use it directly where you need it.

UPDATE#2:  (From comments)
I think this should work:

```
Dim q1 = 
From g In dc1.Hours 
Where g.WorkerId = workerid 
Select New With {g.EntryId, g.Date, g.WorkType.WorkTypeDesc, g.Minutes}
```

Comment: It's even simpler than I thought. Thanks James!